# Accidental deleted partition with gparted

Tags: partition, data-recovery, gparted

I Accidentally deleted a partition, using gparted. It contains valuable data. Can I get the data back?

Comment: Google for how to use `testdisk`. I suggest imaging the drive first.

Comment: The data is still there, you need to somehow discover the start and end block numbers, and fix the partition table. I have no idea how to discover them. As I have only done this when I had previously written down the 2 numbers on a bit of paper. However it should be possible, if the file system has enough structure to be detected using appropriate tools.

Comment: sir actually i have two OS in laptop i deleted one OS then it is saying operating system not found. then i used to gparted to modify boot record but i did not do that and unexpectedly one D partition is deleted and remaining C E are still there as it is which are working fine. now testdisk will work?

Answer (score 3):

If all you did was delete the partition and not reused its space, then the program `testdisk` should have no trouble finding and recovering the partition.

Take this as an opportunity to learn the lesson that if you don't backup your important data, it *will* be lost sooner or later.

Comment: According to Murphy's Law, you will never accidentally delete data which has been backed up.